# Breeze duplicates data on refresh

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm working on a project which uses GUID as its primary key type and also I use breeze and angular on client side. The problem is that when I try to renew the data on client side the received data get added to the old data, however I want refresh the data. I use code first approache to produce metadata for breeze.js
This is a piece of my model class:

```
public class Peripherals
{
    public Guid PeripheralId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
```

and this the function which refreshes the data:

```
  function getAll(forceRemote, page, size, nameFilter) {
        var self = this;
        // Only return a page worth of devices
        var take = size || 20;
        var skip = page ? (page - 1) * size : 0;

        if (self._areItemsLoaded() && !forceRemote) {
            // Get the page of devices from local cache
            return self.$q.when(getByPage());
        }

        // Load all devices to cache via remote query
        return EntityQuery.from('Devices')               
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .toType(entityName)
            .using(self.manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .catch(self._queryFailed);


        function querySucceeded(data) {
            self._areItemsLoaded(true);
            self.log('Retrieved [Devices] from remote data source', data.results.length, true);
            return getByPage();
        }

        function getByPage() {
            var predicate = null;

            if (nameFilter) {
                predicate = _devicePredicate(nameFilter);
            }

            var devices = EntityQuery.from(entityName)
                .where(predicate)
                .orderBy(orderBy)
                .toType(entityName)
                .take(take).skip(skip)
                .using(self.manager)
                .executeLocally();

            return devices;
        }
    }
```

Is the problem with the GUID type? or what?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the guid is always the same for the same record.
Also you should set the primary key as computed on the metadata for the entity